# Copy Selected Rows in datagridview to Pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, datagridview, itext

I am trying to copy a selected row from the datagrid view with mouseclick into a pdf. The code is working, but it copy all rows and not just the one which i selected.

Code :

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
    PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\navee\Desktop\Leihvertrag.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite));
    doc.Open();

    iTextSharp.text.Image Diamant = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(@"C:\Users\navee\Desktop\DiamantPDF.PNG");
    Diamant.ScalePercent(72f);
    doc.Add(Diamant);
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("            \n ________________________________________________________________________________________         \n                                                                      PFANDLEIHHAUS WVB \n                                                                               - Leihvertrag - \n ________________________________________________________________________________________ \n \n \n");
    Paragraph anschrift = new Paragraph("        WVB\n        def \n        11111 abc\n        Tel.0000/0000");
    Paragraph leerzeichen = new Paragraph("\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n               _______________________                                                     _______________________");
    Paragraph unterschrift = new Paragraph("                      Unterschrift Pfänder                                                                     Unterschrift Kunde ");

    Paragraph agbs = new Paragraph("\n \n \n AGB: Der Vertrag ist nicht Widerrufbar ! \n \n Leihgebühr : 1 Monat = 5 €\n                      2 Monate = 10 € \n                      3 Monate  = 15 €");

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {            
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText));
        }

        table.HeaderRows = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1[k,i].Value != null)
                {
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString()));
                } 
            }
        }
        doc.Add(anschrift);
        doc.Add(paragraph);
        doc.Add(table);
        doc.Add(leerzeichen);
        doc.Add(unterschrift);
        doc.Add(agbs);            

        doc.Close();
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\navee\Desktop\Leihvertrag.pdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: You loop through all rows, why do you expect it to add only selected rows?

Comment: could you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: You loop through the first selected rows first, but then you loop through all columns again. Try to contain your loops to the selected rows only. You might also want to take a look at [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx). It would make this a lot easier, I think.

Comment: thanks for your help again mate ! could you just show me how to improve this thing with the loops please. i really need that . :/ trying this for hours :/